Why do i get 0ETH from transaction of 2k
When I swap my KVAI to ETH and it says it successed. I loose nothing of my KVAI and get send 0ETH to my wallet. What is happening and why?
https://arbiscan.io/tx/0x284a9c74452f61123f3fc2030bc3bd8e86aea0eae22d3521f9f7e193546b6204

It is a approve trabsaction. You hadn't swap your token to eth
